# How to list all unversioned files with the SVN CLI and/or SVNKit?

Tags: svn, svnkit

I'm trying to list every un-versioned file in my SVN working copy regardless of their directory depth. Let me start with a scenario on the command line - my ultimate goal is to do this with SVNKit.

If I run the following commands in my home directory,

```
svnadmin create svnrepo
svn mkdir file:///home/foobar/svnrepo/myproj -m "New proj"
svn co file:///home/foobar/svnrepo/myproj
cd myproj
mkdir -p trunk/path/to/new/folder
touch trunk/path/to/new/folder/file.txt
svn status
```

I see the following output,

```
?       trunk
```

What I want to see is `file.txt` in the list. I know if I add `trunk`, then all the files will show up, but I can't do this in my scenario.

In SVNKit I'm calling `getStatusClient().doStatus( new File(myWorkingCopy), SVNRevision.HEAD, SVNDepth.Infinity, false, true, false, false, handler, null)`. My `handler` implements `ISVNStatusHandler` and `ISVNEventHandler` and the `handleStatus()` method only sees that `trunk` is unversioned. Probably as expected.

Does anyone know if it is possible (or how) to get a list of every un-versioned file by querying the status at the root of my working copy with SVNKit?

Thanks

Comment: The SVN CLI part of your question is a duplicate of this question: [How do I get a list of all unversioned files from svn?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/216049/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-all-unversioned-files-from-svn)

Comment: I'm sorry, I saw that but I needed to setup my real question carefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure this is not possible by pure SVNKit functionality (*). Instead, when you encounter an unversioned directory you need to do the unversioned-recursion yourself.

(*) Have a look at `SVNStatusEditor17.getDirStatus`: in the `for(String name : allChildren)` loop, in case of versioned directories (`nodeInfo != null`) there is a recursion. However, in case of `sendUnversioned` there is none.