# Is there a direct way to find out whether a given file is under svn version control?

Tags: svn

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I get a list of all unversioned files from svn?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216049/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-all-unversioned-files-from-svn)

How to determine that a file with a given path is under svn version control or is a generated file from the build.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run `svn st` (from the top level directory), all files which are currently not under versioning control are marked with a `?` before the filename.

Comment: My bad! Should have realised that. Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you check SVN it will show something like a + that it has been added recently. If you didn't create that file yourself, you can take it as being generated from the build.

or you can run a check svn command which is explained here already: [How do I get a list of all unversioned files from SVN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216049/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-all-unversioned-files-from-svn)