# In setup.py that uses setuptools, how can I select only .py files that are in Subversion?

Tags: python, setuptools

In my setup.py file which uses setuptools, I use `packages = find_packages()`. This works fine, except that it includes unversioned `.py` files that are stored in the package folders. I would like it to include only the .py files that I have checked into my Subversion repository. Is that possible and, if so, how?

In essence, I would like the inclusion of `.py` files in the packages to work more like the inclusion of data files enabled with `include_package_data = True`, where only data files that are also checked into Subversion get included.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1  Find a list of files not version controlled using

```
svn status | grep ^?
```

Refer to [How do I get a list of all unversioned files from SVN?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/216049/how-do-i-get-a-list-of-all-unversioned-files-from-svn)

You will have to shell out using something like `subprocess.check_output`.

2 `setuptools.find_packages()` takes an `exclude=` parameter to specify a list of patterns and it will ignore all packages that match these patterns. You will have to send the filenames from setp 1 as `exclude=`.
Refer: http://pythonhosted.org/setuptools/setuptools.html#using-find-packages