# In TFS 2015, adding new files in solution are detected in excluded changes by default.

Tags: tfs

In TFS 2015, adding new files in solution are Detected in excluded changes by default.Is there any setting, that when I set, the new and deleted items directly appears in Included changes!

Comment: I want to re frame the question. I am adding cs files to the solution through Visual studio. These changes are not present in included changes or un tracked files. They are displayed in excluded changes as n files detected. When I promote the changes I am able to check in them. I wanted to know whether they can be directly tracked in included changes.

Answer (score 1):

This functionality was changed in TFS 2012 I think. You used to be able to simply edit the registry. Now you cannot by default change TFS's ignore list but you can override it.

I should point out that the default list is quite good and you should not normally need to include any of the excluded files in your source control so you may want to investigate and review your processes. What files are you wanting to include? .dlls? If so, look into using NuGet.

Nonetheless, you will need to create a .tfignore file at the root level of your source control with the line:

```
!*.dll
```

This will tell TFS to NOT ignore dlls.

See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms245454.aspx#tfignore) for more information and how to create the .tfignore file

Answer (score 0):

If the file is added from VS, it should appear in Included Changes directly. But if the file is added outside VS, there isn't any setting to include them automatically. You need to promote them from "Excluded Changes" manually.

Comment: No , I am adding files through VS still it is shown in excluded changes. In TFS 2010, adding through VS directly changed included changes

Comment: What is the extension of the files you are adding? For example: .dll, .cs, .txt.

Comment: @velagp You may want to refer this question for details: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30196129/what-are-excluded-changes-in-team-foundation-server